# why to update real DOM in Reactjs ,if we get the updates from virtual DOM?

Tags: reactjs

why is there need to update real DOM .I mean we get the updation from virtual DOM .so why is it necessary to update real DOM? Please Help.

Comment: real DOM is real representation of parsed HTML. The browser updates the real DOM for changes to reflect on the user's screen. When you do `document.append(someElement)`, you're mutating real DOM. It's just React has Virtual DOM to do comparison with it's previous iteration (before render) of Virtual DOM and update the real DOM with differences.

Answer (score 0):

As said in @Lakshya Thakur's comment, the real DOM is the representation of parsed HTML. Updating the real DOM changes the user's screen. React has a virtual DOM to compare the current version with the previous version and update the real DOM.